# An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket with HttpClient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I've got a very simple method that basically retrieves string content from a list of passed in urls:

```
foreach (var url in urls)
{
     var content = _httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
}
```

Intermittently, I get the following exception:

> An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

I suspect I'm running out of connections?
If there is some network latency (and it takes a second or so for each url to return) I don't get this error.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Using .Result can cause problems depending on what the current Threading Synchronization Context is.  However, assuming that .Result is not causing the issue, there is a property that limits the number of simultaneous connections allowed.  However, unless you explicitly set it, sometimes it doesn't actually do anything, and you can easily get HttpClient trying to make 100s of simultaneous requests.

So, try adding this line,

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit;
```

I know it looks dumb, but it will actually limit the number of simultaneous connections to 2.  That might prevent whatever strange issue you are seeing.